# Find all Attributes with given Trait

Tags: perl, moose, traits

I've looked and looked but can't seem to find a Moose::Meta function to return all Attributes that have a given trait.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I didn't search deep enough:

Moose::Meta::Role

*$metarole->consumers;
Returns a list of names of classes and roles which consume this role.*

Comment: You should also accept your own answer so that the question won't show up as being open anymore.

Comment: @Moritz Bunkus, I just did the same, but it won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days!

Comment: Ah right, there was that... I've actually never answered myself, so I always forget about that restriction :)